# How can I show full title of a web page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, extension, title-bar

Browsers creators removed long time ago the title of the page from the titlebar, thus preventing user from checking what is looking at.

Does anybody know if it is possible to re-enable the titlebar in Chrome, or if there is any workaround?

I have Chrome 84.0.4147.135 for Windows 10.

The **chrome://flags/#windows10-custom-titlebar** flag does not exist (anymore?)

The **chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md** has gone

Option in "Settings/Appearance" to show standard titlebar has gone too.

Comment: Have you tried to modify the icon used with... put into the chrome properties "target" section: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-windows10-custom-titlebar

Comment: Right click in the title bar and select always show full url's.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 did not work.

Comment: @Moab No such a menuitem here.

Comment: @jump Works for me on the latest version of chrome on all my PC's

Answer (score 1):

To display the full title of a web page in Chrome, hover your cursor over the browser tab where the page is open. A tooltip will appear showing the complete title if it's too long to fit in the tab. This helps you read the entire title without opening a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a chrome extension which solves the issue; unfortunately, it works everywhere... but on stackexchange sites! (and any site which forbids framing). (**EDIT: see at the end for version working on all sites**)

For simple sites it works fine, showing both title and full url, usually both cropped to unacceptable lenght if you have many tabs and many extensions.

It works:

- upon new tab opening
- upon tab refresh
- upon request by clicking on its icon

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "ShowTitle",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "description": "Show page title and url (titlebar replacement)",
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "title": "Test"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {command: "showTitle"}, function(response) {
            //console.log(response.result);
        });
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {command: "showTitle"}, function(response) {
            //console.log(response.result);
        });
    });
});


chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if ((changeInfo.status == 'complete') && (tab.active)) {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {command: "showTitle"}, function(response) {
                //console.log(response.result);
            });
        });
    }
})
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)    {
    console.log(request.command);
    if (request.command == "showTitle") {
        console.log("Adding title frame...");
        TITLE_HEIGHT = 60;

        // Create an iframe which contains title and URL
        frTitle = document.createElement("iframe");
        frTitle.setAttribute("src","")
        frTitle.setAttribute("width",window.innerWidth)
        frTitle.setAttribute("height",TITLE_HEIGHT)
        html = '<body><center style="background-color:#aaaaaa"><span>Title: ' +  document.title  + '</span><br><span>URL: ' + document.location + '</span></center></body>';
        blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
        frTitle.srcdoc = html;

        br = document.createElement("br");

        // Cretae a frame where to copy original page contents:
        frBody = document.createElement("iframe");
        frBody.setAttribute("src",window.location)
        frBody.setAttribute("width",window.innerWidth)
        frBody.setAttribute("height",window.innerHeight-TITLE_HEIGHT)

        orgBody = document.body; // Store original page

        // Create new body containing the two frames:
        newBody = document.createElement("body");
        newBody.appendChild(frTitle);
        newBody.appendChild(br);
        newBody.appendChild(frBody);

        // Replace original body by new one:
        document.body = newBody;

        //sendResponse({result: "success"});
    } else {
        console.log("Another command.");
    }
});
```

---

Edit:

to get it working also on sites which do not allow framing, I had to introduce a toggle function to enable/disable the extension at mouseclick, inside background.js :

```
var enable=false;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {

enable = enable ? false : true;
if(enable){
    //turn on...
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: 'showtitle_on.png' });
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: 'ON' });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'content.js' });
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {command: "showTitle"}, function(response) {
        //console.log(response.result);
            console.log("***ATTIVA***");
        });
    });
}else{
    //turn off...
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: 'showtitle_off.png'});
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: 'Off' });
            console.log("***NON ATTIVA***");
}


});

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function() {
    if(enable){
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {command: "showTitle"}, function(response) {
                //console.log(response.result);
            });
        });
    }
});


chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(enable){
        if ((changeInfo.status == 'complete') && (tab.active)) {
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {command: "showTitle"}, function(response) {
                    //console.log(response.result);
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

I also added default ON status in Manifest.json:

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "ShowTitle",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "showtitle_on.png"
    }
  },
```